# My custom middleware doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware, dingo-api

Something wrong with my custom middleware. It doesn't work. I have registered it in Kernel.php , the `routeMiddleware` array.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    // 'jwt.auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
    'upload.file' => \App\Http\Middleware\Upload::class,
    'admin.settings' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminChange::class,
];
```

And in my middle , I used `dd` to print sth

```
    class AdminChange
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd('i\'m here');
        config(['auth.providers.users.model' => '\App\Models\Useradmin::class']);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And , my api group like this.

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->group([
    'version' => 'v1',
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api',
],function($api){

    $api->group([
        'middleware'=>['admin.settings'],
        'prefix'=>'ad'
    ],function($api){
        include_once(base_path('routes/v1/admin/notice.php'));
    });

    $api->group([
        'middleware' => ['api.auth']
    ],function($api){

    });

});
```

I tried to rename the alias *admin.settings* to other names ,it still did not work.

I couldn't get **i am here** , it seemed the middleware didn't work. Does anyone help?

Comment: the problem lies in route definition , what is `$api->group` ?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi , I use dingo/api to manage my routes. I updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried: `'middleware'=>[App\Http\Middleware\AdminChange::class]`

Comment: @btl I have tried this way , it still did not work.

Comment: Can you check if the auth middlewares working?

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked out of the box (with Laravel routing definitions)

Comment: @commonsense Maybe something wrong with dingo/api router.